# How do I export the mysql results from Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel, csv, export

At first, I learned how to get the results from Database.

```
import pymysql
conn=pymysql.connect(host...................)
curs=conn.cursor()
import csv  
f=open('./kospilist.csv','r')
data=f.readlines()
data_kp=[]
for i in data:
    data_kp.append(i[:-1])


def test():
    for i in range(0,len(data_kp)):
        xp="select date from " + data_kp[i] + " where price is null"
        curs.execute(xp)
        conn.commit()

test()
```

the result will be come out as

datetime.date(2002, 9, 2), None),.......

I want the results of the datas where price is null
It collects the null price from the kospilist excel file. 
I need it for the every tables ( a000010,a000020 ............. a lot of tables exist)

My expectation is

[image]

I want to save the datas as csv file like this image

the problem is the result comes out, but I don't know how to export to csv files.
I know how to write in python and export,
but I don't get it.. how to export the data from mysql database.
Cuz I'm beginner so I'm not good at mixture.

my effort to figure out is ..

```
with open('./test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

def tablename():
    for i in data_kp
         writer.writerow['data_kp']
         writer.writerow[\n]

def test():
    for i in range(0,len(data_kp)):
        xp="select date from " + data_kp[i] + " where price is null"
        curs.execute(xp)
        result= cursor.fetchall()
        for i in result
        writer. writerow[result]
        conn.commit()


test()
```

well, I had read a lot from google, so I'm confused.. xlsxwriter or openpyxl something.. I need some help. At least hint for my wrong code

Comment: Python docs on reading/writing CSV @ https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.

Comment: It doesn;'t work..